# Нужно создать мини программу

Tags: pascal

Надо в паскалье выполнить задание, от 1 до 100 вывести цисла, пропуская одну цифру 2,4,6,8 и тд

Comment: никто думать не хочет :( обидно все таки мир катится не в нужную сторону.

Comment: @Данияр, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так ещё проще:

```
Var
  i: Byte;

begin
  For i:=1 To 50 Do
    WriteLn(i*2);
  WriteLn;
  WriteLn('Press ENTER!!!');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Непонятно одно: зачем с такими простыми задачками на форум лезть? Самому подумать что-ли лень?

Comment: молодцом. :)

>ReadLn;  ;)

Comment: Писал на Delphi, но пальцы всё равно помнят этот злой цикл, надеюсь, что мозг сумеет вовремя среагировать и остановить его написание.

Answer (score 0):

Вот должно работать:

```
program lll;
var i;

begin
  i = 0;
  while(i<=100)
  begin 
    i := i+2;
    writeln(i);
  end;
end.
```